# How can I set imageView coming from Stream

Tags: java, android

I am trying to get imagefiles as stream from asset folder .And then bind this stream   an `ImageView` control.Finally Show them in the screen .But when I run this code Nothing happens Nothing will display.I dont get any exception But I think I missed out something.

This is what I have

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private ImageView imgV=null;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        AssetManager am=getAssets();
        try {
            String []names=am.list("image");
            InputStream is=am.open("image/"+names[0]);
            Bitmap b=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
            imgV.setImageBitmap(b);
            this.addContentView(imgV, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



    }


@Edit
05-02 16:01:44.768: E/AndroidRuntime(2862): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-02 16:01:44.768: E/AndroidRuntime(2862): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.vcxz/com.example.vcxz.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-02 16:01:44.768: E/AndroidRuntime(2862):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
05-02 16:01:44.768: E/AndroidRuntime(2862):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
05-02 16:01:44.768: E/AndroidRuntime(2862):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
05-02 16:01:44.768: E/AndroidRuntime(2862):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
05-02 16:01:44.768: E/AndroidRuntime(2862):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-02 16:01:44.768: E/AndroidRuntime(2862):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-02 16:01:44.768: E/AndroidRuntime(2862):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
05-02 16:01:44.768: E/AndroidRuntime(2862):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-02 16:01:44.768: E/AndroidRuntime(2862):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
05-02 16:01:44.768: E/AndroidRuntime(2862):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
05-02 16:01:44.768: E/AndroidRuntime(2862):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
05-02 16:01:44.768: E/AndroidRuntime(2862):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-02 16:01:44.768: E/AndroidRuntime(2862): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-02 16:01:44.768: E/AndroidRuntime(2862):     at com.example.vcxz.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:39)
05-02 16:01:44.768: E/AndroidRuntime(2862):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
05-02 16:01:44.768: E/AndroidRuntime(2862):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
05-02 16:01:44.768: E/AndroidRuntime(2862):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
05-02 16:01:44.768: E/AndroidRuntime(2862):     ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you should be getting a FileNotFoundException may be you should reconnect the device that you are testing with.

Your files are in "image" folder in assets. But you try to open directly from assets. Also you should be creating the `ImageView` first. Write this code and it will work.

```
    AssetManager am = getResources().getAssets();
    try {
        imgV = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
        String[] names = am.list("image");          
        InputStream is = am.open("image/"+names[0]);
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
        imgV.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        is.close();
        this.addContentView(imgV, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you @Sir SC But I am getting this exception above

Comment: at com.example.vcxz.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:39)
what is your line 39 in MainActivity? can you update your question

Comment: sure;line 39 refers this imgV.setImageBitmap(b);

Comment: did you change whole try/catch block with the one I wrote? I tested it before writing so it is working.

Comment: No,updated my code as you suggested righ now.Still same exception

Comment: No you didn't :) you are still missing this: imgV = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());

Comment: I am sooooo sory sir.need some sleep